# Meaning of "get off the hammock"

Tags: phrases, idioms

Is the phrase *get off the hammock* idiomatic, and what does it mean if it is?

Comment: A hammock is something one can _get off (of)_, but more likely one would _get out of_ it. It would depend on whether it's a flattened "lawn hammock" -- one can _get off (of)_ anything that's flat -- or a real string _hamaca_, which one has _to get out of_ because it's 3-dimensional.

Comment: I have never heard that phrase but, assuming it's not being used literally, I would say that it means "stop being lazy" or "get up and do something", as hammocks are generally associated with just comfortably relaxing and/or dozing.

Answer (score 1):

> **Hammock:** a type of bed used especially outside , consisting of a net or long piece of strong cloth that you tie between two trees or
>   poles so that it swings (= moves sideways through the air )

The phrase 'to get off the hammock' means to be productive and stop wasting time. On the contrary "to hit the hammock" means to get some rest and chill.